# WAMP and XAMPP gives Internal Server Error

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]   
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-ZA-Z]+) user.php?page=$1 [NC,L]   
</IfModule>
```

I want to remove .php extension from all pages so I use upper 4 lines and i also want to make my URL more clean so i apply the last line. **But as i apply this last line, both XAMPP and WAMP started to show Internal Server Error**. I wanna know what's the cause of it.

If my codes are wrong, then please suggest me how to make URL more clean like bellow:

**http://localhost/project/user?user=ROYAL**

I wanna make it:

**http://localhost/project/user/ROYAL**

Comment: Hello, please remove the last paragraph or edit it because it seems like that is a second question that is unrelated to the URL rewrite problem.

Comment: @tima  Now, I removed the last paragraph can now you tell me something?

Comment: I was doing a review of your post. I'm not an expert on URL re-write, but at least now it will not get closed as too broad.

Comment: Your .htaccess is already configured to remove the php extension but for checking the internal server error we need more information do you have any server logs ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from my brother:
I just have to change:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-ZA-Z]+) user.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

into:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([\w+\s-]+)$ user?page=$1
```

This is only a Apache version issue, back slash is added to avoid escaping
This problem is identified as **RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression**